# Add function definition selectively to a python namespace

Tags: c++, python-2.7, boost-python

I want to controll which function is allowed to reach from a python code.

Here the struct, where I defined some functions for the Python to extend:

```
struct Worldb
{
    void messagewindow(std::string msg) { functions.Messagewindow(msg); }
    void setnumber(int value) { publicnumber=value; }
    string getnumber() { return functions.converttostring(publicnumber); }
    int publicnumber;
};
```

And here is the code ,where I add the definition to the code and send the Python code to the compiler:

```
Py_Initialize();

worldb.publicnumber = 1;

bp::object main_module = bp::import("__main__");
bp::object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");


main_namespace["Worldb"] = bp::class_<Worldb>("Worldb")
    .def("messagewindow", &Worldb::messagewindow)
    .def("setnumber", &Worldb::setnumber)
    .def("getnumber", &Worldb::getnumber);

main_namespace["cpp"] = bp::ptr(&worldb);//to prevent the worldb object copied 

bp::object compileit;
try
{
     compileit = exec(
         "cpp.messagewindow(cpp.getnumber())\n"
        "cpp.setnumber(8)\n",
        main_namespace);

}
catch(bp::error_already_set &)
```

I can extend functions into the Python manually with the .def easily, but I can't find any solution to put it in some kind of "if" statement, to check it is allowed to add to the python or not. Of course I can put each function into an unique namespace, but that is far from elegant and I think it's maybe waste some memory too.

Sorry for my bad english and thank you for any advice you give.

Comment: You don't need to have all the calls to `bp::class_::def` in one statement. Being able to chain them like that is just for convenience...

Comment: How can I add all def separately?  In every tutorial I seen it's chained like this, and I am soo beginner with templates, I have no idea how it works.

Comment: Like this: https://pastebin.com/cviZ8HmX -- I'll write up an answer in a bit. First you construct an instance of `bp::class_<Worldb>` and store it in a variable. Then you proceed to call `def` on this object instance as many times as necessary. When complete, you finally assign it to `main_namespace["Worldb"]`. I enclose the whole snippet in its own scope, since we don't need the temporary variable after the last assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to have everything in one statement -- the ability to chain the calls is just a matter of convenience (`def` and other member functions return reference to the instance they were invoked on to let this happen).

If we analyze the statement

```
main_namespace["Worldb"] = bp::class_<Worldb>("Worldb")
    .def("messagewindow", &Worldb::messagewindow)
    .def("setnumber", &Worldb::setnumber)
    .def("getnumber", &Worldb::getnumber);
```

we'll see that it performs the following functions in sequence:

- Creates a new instance of `class_<Worldb>`
- Calls its member function `def` to expose `messagewindow`
- Calls its member function `def` to expose `setnumber`
- Calls its member function `def` to expose `getnumber`
- Assigns it to `main_namespace["Worldb"]`.

We can rewrite this to have each part as a separate statement in the following manner:

```
{
    bp::class_<Worldb> test_binding = bp::class_<Worldb>("Worldb");
    test_binding.def("messagewindow", &Worldb::messagewindow);
    test_binding.def("setnumber", &Worldb::setnumber);
    test_binding.def("getnumber", &Worldb::getnumber);

    main_namespace["Worldb"] = test_binding;
}
```

Note: We introduce a new scope to limit the lifetime of `test_binding`, which is no longer needed after the assignment.

Having done so, it is trivial to expose the individual methods conditionally.

### Sample Code

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

namespace bp = boost::python;

struct test
{
    void one() {}
    void two() {}
    void three() {}
};

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();

    try {
        bp::object main_module = bp::import("__main__");
        bp::object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");

        // Simple bitmap of methods to expose:
        // * bit 0 -> one()
        // * bit 1 -> two()
        // * bit 2 -> three()
        uint32_t method_mask(5);

        {
            // Limit the scope of `test_binding` variable
            bp::class_<test> test_binding = bp::class_<test>("test");
            if ((method_mask & 1) == 1) {
                test_binding.def("one", &test::one);
            }
            if ((method_mask & 2) == 2) {
                test_binding.def("two", &test::two);
            }
            if ((method_mask & 4) == 4) {
                test_binding.def("three", &test::three);
            }

            main_namespace["test"] = test_binding;
        }

        exec("print dir(test)\n", main_namespace);
    } catch (bp::error_already_set &) {
        PyErr_Print();
    }

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

### Console Output

Note: We expect `one()` and `three()` to be exposed. I re-formatted the output for better readability.

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__'
    , '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__instance_size__'
    , '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__'
    , '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__'
    , 'one', 'three']
```

### References

- Documentation of [`boost::python::class_`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/high_level_components.html#high_level_components.boost_python_class_hpp)